# Issues with the AWK function

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

Does Awk have a limit to the amount of data it can process?

```
for i in "052" "064" "060" "070" "074" "076" "178"
do
        awk -v f="${i}" -F, 'match ($1,f) { print $2","$3 }' uls.csv > ul$i.csv
        awk -v f="${i}" -F, 'match ($1,f) { print $2","$3 }' dls.csv > dl$i.csv
        awk -v n="${i}" -F, 'match ($1,n) { print $2","$3 }' dlsur.csv >> dlu$i.csv
        awk -v k="${i}" -F, 'match ($1,k) { print $2","$3 }' dailyd.csv >> dla$i.csv
        awk -v m="${i}" -F, 'match ($1,m) { print $2","$3 }' dailyu.csv >> ula$i.csv

done
```

When I run that piece of code, it basically pulls data from csv files and creates new files.
that piece of code works perfectly.
but when i add an extra file (in the for loop), for example "180" it will create that file, but will also include a few lines of data from other files. I went over the code many times. I even checked the raw data before it goes into this loop, and it is all correct. This seems like a glitch in awk.
Do I need to apply a wait function so that it can catch up?

Comment: Your regular expression is very general; are you sure it just isn't matching more lines than intended?

Comment: It is not. Each of these lines have a unique id, which is also partly the name of the file, so 052 and 064 are all ids.

Comment: But could the string appear elsewhere in the line? `$0` is the entire line, not the first field. Perhaps you want `match($1, f)` instead.

Comment: when i open up the file after the loop, it displays the id of the new file, but data of the new id and another id.

Comment: Are the files originally from a window's PC?  When I import files from windows onto linux for awking I generally need to vi them and `:set ff=unix` and `:set nobomb` to get them to behave as expected.

Comment: Its all from linux, anyway Chepner was right, i changed it to $1,f and it works,, but i rechecked my data, and there are no repeating values, so it cant be matching with anything else.. the issue is solved, but I still do not know why..

Comment: Can you paste any of the erroneously matched lines and indicate which file they ended up in?

Comment: @user2883071 Your `match($0,"180")`, since it contains nothing that restricts the match to e.g. word or field boundaries, would match "61802" or such - perhaps that's how your "unexpected matches" occur...

Comment: does it skip over commas too? for example if it is 0,80 - then would it match? because I am working with a large amount of data.

Comment: @user2883071 - see my answer and update your question so we can help you.

Comment: Its alright, this solution works, ill look into it more and update it if needed

Comment: a) You have a workaround that hides the problem with this specific set of input files and b) your whole approach of that shell loop and multiple awk invocations is wrong. We can help you with both issues if you provide the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

Also something like

```
for file in uls dls dlsur dailyd dailyu; do
    awk -F, -vOFS=, -vfile=$i '$1 ~ /052|064|060|070|074|076|178/ {print $2,$3 >> file$1.csv}' $file.csv
done
```

is probably better if it does what you want. Many fewer invocations of awk and loops through your files. (Slightly different output file names. That would be fixable but complicate the script a bit more than I thought was necessary for the purpose.)

Answer (score 1):

No. What you say you think is happening cannot be happening - awk WILL NOT randomly pull data from un-specified files and put it in it's output stream.

Note that in your 3rd and subsequent lines you are using '>>' instead of '>' for your output redirection - have you accounted for that?

If you update your question (i.e. do NOT try to do it in a comment!) to tell us what you're trying to do with some representative sample input and expected output (just 2 input files, not 5, should be enough to explain your problem), we can help you write a correct script to do that.

Comment: It works now, it's just that I was having trouble trying to figure out why it worked.

Comment: If you don't know what was causing the problem then how do you know it won't re-appear in future when you have some different input in your files? Obviously it's something about the way you are parsing your input that was causing your problem since by changing where you look in the input file you changed the output but that certainly doesn't mean you've solved the problem, just that the problem has disappeared for now given your current, specific set of input. It will re-appear in future when you least expect is as you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to approach the problem.